# Show only one of two header elements below a width of 1000px

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to add an additional menu bar underneath the existing `header` in a WordPress theme. I implemented my menu, also using the `header` tag, by inserting raw HTML code (some themes allow you to do so). But it should only be visible when the viewport width is less than 1000px.

I would love to do this with a media query, but the problem is that both my menu,  as well as the existing menu use the `header` tag, so my CSS rule would hide both menus below a viewport width of 1000px.

Anyway, here's the code I was working with. Does anyone notice anything, why this isn't working?

```js
function toggle_visibility(.scroll-nav-down) {
  var screen_width = window.innerWidth;
  if (screen_width <= 1000) {
    // Screen is smaller than (or equal to) 1000px
    var e = document.getElementById(.scroll-nav-down);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      e.style.display = 'block';
    }
  } else {
    // do something if it's larger
    e.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

**Edit:** I'm really struggeling getting back to working with css. I'm trying to use the Media Query solution, but I'm facing problems. I guess it is the  instead of only . But if I remove the  and change it to , I'm messing up the JavaScript a friend wrote me some time ago. And yes, I'm not into JavaScript at all. So here's the whole code, maybe it helps solving my problem... 
-> I added the  part only for the image, to demonstrate the effect.

**Note**: If you change the css for the "#headerdiv" to a simple "header" and in the last JavaScript line the 'headerdiv' to a simple 'header', the code is working as it should. But not disappearing under a 1000px widht.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#headerdiv {
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.scroll-nav-up {
  top: -40px;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #headerdiv {
    display:none;
  }
}
main {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
) repeat;
  height: 2000px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ScrollNav = function(elem, delta) {
    this.m_Delta = delta;
    this.m_LastScrollTop = 0;
    this.m_Element = elem;
    $(window).on("scroll", null, {ScrollNav: this}, this.OnWindowScroll);
};

ScrollNav.prototype.OnWindowScroll = function(e) {

    var scrolledTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var Nav = e.data.ScrollNav;

    if(Math.abs(Nav.m_LastScrollTop - scrolledTop) <= Nav.m_Delta) {
        return;
    }

    if(scrolledTop > Nav.m_LastScrollTop && scrolledTop > $(Nav.m_Element).outerHeight()) {
        $(Nav.m_Element).removeClass('scroll-nav-down').addClass('scroll-nav-up');
    } else if(scrolledTop + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $(Nav.m_Element).removeClass('scroll-nav-up').addClass('scroll-nav-down');
    }

    Nav.m_LastScrollTop = scrolledTop;
}
// HOW TO USE!
var scroll = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    // new ScrollNav('ZielElement', Delta);
    scroll = new ScrollNav('headerdiv', 5);
});
</script>




<body>
  <header id="headerdiv" class="scroll-nav-down">
    This is your menu.
  </header>
  <main>
    This is your body.
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say _"it should only be visible below 1000px"_ do you mean that the additional menu should only be visible for screens with a width of less than 1000px? Also, what does _"the standart tag used in the code is also used in the theme"_ mean?

Comment: `.scroll-nav-down` is not a valid ID and certainly not without quotes. You maybe mean `function toggle_visibility(passedID)` using `var ele = document.getElementById(passedID);` and then pass the ID to the function when you call it

Comment: Why JavaScript? it could be done by CSS

Comment: "*I would love to do this with a media query, but the problem is, that **the standard tag used in the code is also used in the theme.***" -- Not really understanding what you mean here.

Comment: Consider using a media query listener to run JS at or below/above a certain width

Comment: @domsson Yeah, the menu should be only visible for screens with less than a 1000px.
In this case, I used a <header> tag in the code (I implemented raw html code into wordpress, some themes allow you to do so). But the <header> tag is also used by the theme, which meanes, that any styling of <header> also affects the header given by the theme...

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Could you please specify, what css tags you mean? :)

Comment: Jasper, it shouldn't be a problem that there is another `header` - just give yours a unique `id` or a `class` that allows you to target it via CSS. Problem solved. :)

Comment: @Jasper you can control visibility using css, e.g: `display`. and apply your style in specific size using `media query`, e.g: `@media (max-width: 1000px) { .menu { display: block; } }`

Comment: Jasper, I've edited your question text to incorporate the new information from your comment. If you don't agree with the edit, feel free to roll the changes back (or ask me to do so). Apart from that, I think the solution really is to give your `header` a `class` or `id`, then use a media query as you originally had planned. No need for JS.

Comment: @domsson Thanks for the changes, they're fine for me. And I tried the solution you suggested, without any success... Do you mind have another look at the code? I added the whole code, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this.
The trick is to add event listener for resize event, because otherwise your function will be called just once.

```js
function toggle_visibility() {
  var screen_width = window.innerWidth;
  if (screen_width <= 1000) {
    // Screen is smaller than (or equal to) 1000px
    var e = document.getElementById('scroll-nav-down');
    if (e.style.display == 'block') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      e.style.display = 'block';
    }
  } else {
    // do something if it's larger
    e.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  
 document.addEventListner('resize', toggle_visibility);
```